# Wrap MediaWiki in another website

Tags: mediawiki

I want to wrap a mediawiki site inside another site - using the header.inc and footer.inc files that the rest of the website's html files use.
I'm not familiar with php, is there a 'masterpage' file somewhere I can put them in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a custom skin, or edit one of the default skins, such as monobook. They control most of the basic presentation code. [Here is one short tutorial on creating a custom skin](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/mediawiki/mediawiki_skins.htm). The files usually live in the `/skins/` folder; if you skim through one, you can find where the HTML begins and ends.

You can include another file using the [PHP include function](http://www.php.net/function.include), like so:

```
<html>
...
<body>
<?php
include 'header.inc';
?>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference in the LocalSettings.php you can also prevent users from using any other skin.

```
$wgDefaultSkin = 'myskin';
$wgAllowUserSkin = false;
$wgSkipSkins = array( "chick", "cologneblue", "monobook", "modern", "myskin", "nostalgia", "simple", "standard" );
```

Comment: These two settings are necessary but not enough to prevent users from using other skins. 

You also have to set this configuration settings as well:

$wgAllowUserSkin = false; 

(true by default).